# Add summary/additional text to alertDialog single choice items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to add a summary or a additional text to a alertDialog with single choice items? I'd like to have a bold header and a small text with some extra informations.

Answer (score 8):

Google says:

> "Because the list appears in the dialog's content area, the dialog cannot show both a message and a list":
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

It seems that buttons, message and multiple choice items are exclusive.
If you want to have both message and multiple choice item, you'll have to do something custom with your own DialogFragment

Answer (score -3):

set the title and then the message:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
```

Comment: ..and where are now the single choice items requested in the question?

Answer (score -3):

*You can use in built method `setSingleChoiceItems` of AlertDialog -*

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(10); //small text font
dialog.setTitle("Colors");
dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });
```

Comment: .. and where is the text on the AlertDialog the question asks for? I think this is all about having BOTH single choice items and message text in a standard AlertDialog (probably not possible without custom view)